# Can I trigger a mouse double click, by holding down the primary button, after a delay?

Tags: mouse, input-devices

Can I change setting so that the the mouse double-clicks by holding down the primary mouse button?  I do not want hover-click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's easy if you're willing to modify one little line in the source ;)

- Get the *mousetweaks* source (`apt-get source mousetweaks`)
- Get its build dependencies (`sudo apt-get build-dep mousetweaks` and then `sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot`)
- Inside the file `mousetweaks-3.4.1/src/mt-main.c`, around line 375 (may differ for you) find this bit:

  ```
  static void
  mt_main_do_secondary_click (MtData *mt)
  {
  mt->ssc_finished = FALSE;
  mt_main_generate_button_event (mt, 3, CLICK, CurrentTime);
  }
  ```
- Change part in parentheses in the bolded line to `(mt, 1, DOUBLE_CLICK, 40)`

  - This modifies the code so that the "simulated secondary click" becomes a "simulated primary double click" instead ;)
- From within the `mousetweaks-3.4.1` directory, run `dpkg-source --commit`, and name your patch anything (it doesn't matter)
- Then run `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` and wait for a bit...
- You will find the appropriate `mousetweaks*.deb` file in the parent directory. Install it with `sudo dpkg -i`, enable the "simulated secondary click option, set the time, and enjoy! (note: the double-click occurs when you release the held button...)
- Please add in the comments if you have any problem modifying/building the package.

Answer (score -1):

Go to System Settings > Universal Access > Pointing and clicking
Now enable hover click. Adjust delay and motion threshold as your need.

[image]

Comment: -1 Thanks, but as I specified I want holding down the mouse button to trigger the double-click.  I've tried the hover-click before and I find it not good at all, triggers when I don't want it to and if I up the delay I lose the convenience.